# Concatenate string field in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have below data in my detail section.

```
Contract No 
VTC/2013/0026
VTC/2013/0028
VTC/2013/0030
```

These data are belong to a one field in a table and there can be more.

I want to display the same details in the report header like below.

```
VTC/2013/0026, VTC/2013/0028, VTC/2013/0030, ...
```

How can I do that without using a sub-report?

Comment: where are fetching these contract No in DataTable?

Comment: Yes, from a data table.

Comment: by iterating through dt(DataTable) you can concatenate values in dt

Comment: Can you explain the steps? I searched, but couldn't find it.

Comment: string str=""; for(int i=0;i<dt.rows.count;i++){ str=str+", "+dt.rows[i]["ContractNo"].toString();}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow below steps:

1. Create a formula `Concat` and write below code and place in right most part of the report.

Shared Stringvar a;

a:=a+Contract No+", " ;

1. now create one more formula `display` and place in report header.

   `EvaluateAfter(@Concat);
   Shared Stringvar a;
   a`

Comment: It shows only the top record. I think I need to use a loop to read through all the rows in contract no field.

Comment: keep the concat formula in detail section then it will show all records

Comment: If I place the display formula in report footer, it shows all the records. But when I place it in the report header, it shows only the first record. Any idea?

Comment: have you used `EvaluateAfter`

Comment: Yes. I finally able to do it like this,

WhileReadingRecords;
Global StringVar a;
a := a + ContractNo + ", "

WhilePrintingRecords;
Global Stringvar a;
a